# Locking/Synchronize problem - Backend code execute faster than database saving

Tags: c#, database, transactions, synchronization, locking

I have a simple example about generating invoice number for new invoice below:

```
// API generate invoice number
public void PublishInvoice(Object invoiceData)
{
    lock (companyInfo) // (1) if request is the same company will be blocked
    {
        int invoiceNo = GetNextNo(); // (2) get new invoice number from database (next no = current no + 1)
        invoiceData.InvoiceNo = invoiceNo; // (3) set invoice number to invoice data
        Save(invoiceData); // (4) save invoice data to database
    }
}
```

The problem that I encountered is if two requests simultaneously call this API, the second request will be blocked at (1), when the first request completed executing (after 4) then the second request executes (2) to get next invoice number but the invoice of the first request hasn't saved to the database yet, so the second invoice got the same invoice number with the first invoice.

---

My question is how can I handle this problem. I have anxiety about performance when I block in the database (I think about trigger or constraints or transaction)

---

*Additional:* I have created a trigger, it will fire before creating a new invoice, it will check the invoice number has already available or not, and it worked, but I hope that will have a better solution (base on availability technology), b/c I don't want have to check each insert request.

Comment: What Database System is that? Most SQL DBs provide a means to have auto-increment columns.

Comment: Also: How is `GetNextNo` implemented? This shouldn't be a problem if you have some kind of "Sequence", which will have atomic "incrementAndGet" functionality.

Comment: I use SQL Server DB. I cannot use auto-increment because the invoice number depends on some another fields. with sequence, when you call sequence and the next number generated but something failed in this transaction, the sequence won't be rollback and my business will get wrong.

Comment: I see. I think in that case you're stuck with a transaction that includes both creation of the Invoice number and insert.

Comment: Yes, if something wrong, the invoice will be not created and invoice number as well

Answer (score 0):

As @Fildor mentioned:

> Most SQL DBs provide a means to have auto-increment columns.

And not only SQL. So, if you use that, you may not need `lock (companyInfo)` at all. Moreover, if your code is part of some web api, it is possible that you don't even have the same `companyInfo` instance.

It would be much better to use **atomic** increment feature of your database.
For example, with Mongo DB:

```
var collection = Get your collection here
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("AtomicNumbers", "Invoices");
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Inc("Counter", 1);
var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>() { IsUpsert = true, ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After };
var result = collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options);
int newInvoiceNumber = result["Counter"].AsInt32;
```

Example with MSSQL:

```
+------------+---------+
| id         | Counter |
+------------+---------+
| Invoices   | 2       |
+------------+---------+
| OtherStuff | 17      |
+------------+---------+

UPDATE AtomicNumbers SET Counter = Counter + 1 where id = 'Invoices'
```

Comment: Is AtomicNumbers is the manually created table? Is newInvoiceNumber result the same result of my function GetNextNo() (both get from database). I will get the same error when AtomicNumbers still hasn't saved completely yet (and the second request is coming).

Comment: Yes, all these tables are manually created. You can use them from within your `GetNextNo()` and return `int` value for `invoiceNo`. You won't get same errors because **atomic** operation makes sure you get different `invoiceNo` each time.

Comment: you mean it the same auto-increment mechanism. I haven't heard atomic operation before. Can you give me some documents about this?